# Enabling NTLM on firefox not working

Tags: authentication, firefox, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, ntlm

I've been trying to get NTLM working on firefox but none of the options are working for me. They all point to setting:

- network.*-uris

  setting: network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies, network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn, network.auth.force-generic-ntlm & network.auth.force-generic-ntlm-v1

I've tried different combinations for the URIs as well:

- https://some.example.com
- some.example.com
- example.com
- .some.example.com
- .example.com
- *some.example.com
- *example.com
- *.example.com
- *.some.example.com

I need to be able to get the login box to appear. I got it to work on chrome and internet explorer by adding the site to the trusted lists. Firefox just gives me a 401

Thanks in advance

Comment: Poorly asked question.  See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

1. In Firefox, modify "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris" to include your app url, e.g. foo.yourcompany.com
2. Restart Firefox

Comment: In fact, this is what OP actually already tried: he tried to set all the possible values into all the "network.*-uris" settings if I understand him correctly.

Comment: The OP never stated that he restarted Firefox, nor did he clearly indicate that he included the URI of his app URL.  We can only guess at his lack of clarity.